# Another MYSQL Join issue

Tags: mysql, join

Hi there I'm really struggling getting the following sql query to work, i apologise in advance if ive made a mash of this but im still learning the full advanced areas of SQL.

Here is my code...

```
"SELECT *,(((acos(sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * 
sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * 
cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$longitude."- `longitude`)*pi()/180))))
*180/pi())*60*1.1515) as distance 
FROM `locations`  l HAVING distance <= '".$distance."' JOIN 
(SELECT * users) u
ON (l.id = u.basic_location)
            WHERE u.id != A $AND2
            ORDER BY distance ASC"
```

I keep getting the following error message...

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'JOIN (SELECT * users) u ON (l.id = u.basic_location) WHERE u.id' at line 1
```

Ive tried many combinations of this but ive become stumped and was looking for some help?

Comment: try putting your distance comparison in the where clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `JOIN` should follow right after `FROM tablename` or another `JOIN`
2. You should use `WHERE`, not `HAVING` in this case
3. You should `JOIN users u`, not subquery (in this case it makes no sense)

Comment: Yes correctiong this and changing it slightly corrected the issue thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    "SELECT *,

        (((( SELECT 
        acos(
            sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * 
            sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+
            cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * 
            cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * 
            cos(((".$longitude."- `longitude`)*pi()/180))
            ))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) as distance
    FROM `locations`  l )X
    JOIN users u
ON (X.id = u.basic_location)
WHERE u.id != A $AND2
AND distance <= '".$distance."'
ORDER BY distance ASC"
```

Changes

1) `HAVING distance <=` needs to be changed to `WHERE distance <=` .Please note that use *HAVING clause* for filtering only if you have any aggregate function like SUM,COUNT etc. For any normal filter operation use *WHERE clause*

2) Join syntax is:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.Id = t2.Id
Where t1.<Some condition>
AND t2.<some Condition>
```

And not

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1 Where t1.<Some condition>
JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.Id = t2.Id
Where t2.<some Condition>
```

If you need to filter from the first table before joining then do like

```
SELECT X.*,Y.* 
FROM (SELECT * FROM Table1 t1 Where t1.<Some condition>) X
JOIN (SELECT * FROM Table2 t2) Y
ON X.Id = Y.Id
Where Y.<some Condition>
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: I donot have MySQL editor(so may be the formatting will be incorrect). But please check the comments I provided. It must work in any DB.

Comment: tip: find for `WHERE` in your query

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from
(SELECT *,
(((acos(sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * 
sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+
cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * 
cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * 
cos(((".$longitude."- `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*
180/pi())*60*1.1515) as distance 
FROM `locations`  l  INNER JOIN 
`users` u
ON l.id = u.basic_location
WHERE u.id != A $AND2) derived_table dt
where dt.distance <= '".$distance."'
ORDER BY dt.distance ASC
```

Comment: Hi thanks using this shows a different error of "Every derived table must have its own alias" any ideas?